# Stuck on proof of an inequality, xy < $\frac{x^p}{p} + \frac{y^q}{q}$

Tags: real-analysis

Need to prove xy $\leq \frac{x^p}{p} + \frac{y^q}{q}$ for all $x>0, y>0$ and find the case where equality holds. We are given that $p>1$ and $q=\frac{p}{p-1}$

I found the case where equality holds, $y=x^{p-1}$, by using algebra but am having trouble proving the inequality. It is in our differentiation chapter so I was thinking of trying to use the Mean Value theorem but am a little stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $y > 0$ the inequality is equivalent to
$$x y^{1-q} \le \frac{x^p}{p y^q} + \frac 1 q.$$
But 
$$\frac{x^p}{y^q} = (xy^{1-q})^p$$ so it suffices to show that
$$ xy^{1-q} \le \frac 1p (xy^{1-q})^p + \frac 1q$$ for all $x,y > 0$.

The function $$\phi(t) = \frac 1q + \frac 1p t^p - t$$ has derivative $$\phi'(t) = t^{p-1} - 1$$ which is negative if $0 < t < 1$ and positive if $t > 1$. Thus $\phi$ has a minimum on $(0,\infty)$ at $t = 1$. Since $\phi(1) = 0$ you have  $\phi(t) \ge 0$ for all $t > 0$. With $t = xy^{1-q}$ you arrive at $$xy^{1-q} \le \frac 1p (xy^{1-q})^p + \frac 1q$$ for all $x,y > 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact that the logaritmic function is concave and the fact that $1/p+1/q=1$.